# Javascript (jQuery) nested div with class does not get selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

There is an AngularJS app with a big dataset (many bindings on a page) and I'm using a md-virtual-repeat for increasing performance. As I understood, the md-virtual-repeat directive does not fully work within an HTML `table` so I'm using a div-based table. It contains nested divs in a single row:

```
<md-virtual-repeat-container class="table-body" navigable>
    <div layout="row" md-virtual-repeat="data in vm.dataset" flex class="item-row">

        <div class="item-cell">
            <input type="text" ng-model="data.name">
        </div>

        <div layout="row" class="unit-container">
            <div class="item-cell" flex ng-repeat="_ in data.semiannual track by $index" ng-class="{'separator' : $index == 0}">
                <input type="number" ng-model="data.semiannual[$index]">
            </div>
        </div>

                 <!-- more unit-container divs with item-cell divs here -->       

   </div>    <!-- end of row div -->
</md-virtual-repeat-container>
```

Now I need to select the divs with class `item-cell` with Javascript in order to do some manipulation, for example, column hovering. The problem is that it does not get selected. Here are some ways I've tried to do the thing:

```
$('.item-cell').hover(function(){ ... }, function(){ ... });
```

also

```
$('.item-cell').on('mouseenter', function(){ ... });
```

also using `mouseover` and no success. I also tried with more specific selectors like: `$('div.item-row div.item-cell')` and nada.
I supposed this is because of the nested thing, but there are also `item-cell` divs which are not nested (not children of `unit-container` class) and they do not get selected as well.

Additional info: the `item-row` div has a :hover pseudo-class defined in CSS over it.

I've seen some similar question on SO with solution of changing the .hover() to on('mouseenter') but it didn't work for me.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you certain Angular have compiled the DOM when you attempt to access the element?If you do it in the body of a controller, chances are that the DOM doesn't yet exist. Have you tried wrapping it in `$timeout(..)`?

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen I'm doing it in the `link` function of the `navigable` directive which is given as an attribute on the `md-virtual-repeat-container` element. Selecting a regular `div` is working fine.

Comment: Hmm, it might be the virtual repeat messing with you. It only renders the DOM that can be seen in the viewport (represented by the container), so depending on the virtual repeat implementation it might first clear all nested elements (including events) and recreate only the visible. That would cause your events to be removed.

Comment: Never thought about that :/

Comment: One way around it is to apply the directive to the row element instead (where the `md-virtual-repeat` is applied) and register (and destroy) the events in that directive. That way, even when they're removed by the virtual repeat, the events will be recreated with the elements.

Comment: Ok, there is something. 
The direct children of the `item-row` div get selected, but the ones within the `unit-container` div don't. Anyway, thanks so far for help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149354/discussion-between-marius-adauge-and-nikolaj-dam-larsen).